# How do I get a range or array for every minute in a day in Ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby, datetime, date

I know there is the Date#step method, however it wants days for steps.  I need a range or array for every minute in a given day (1440 entries).

What's the best, and most effeicient way to do this in Ruby 1.9.3?

Ultimately, I'm going to format the output to be used like this:

```
00:00:00
00:01:00
00:02:00
...
23:59:00
```

Comment: What about days that have 23 hours or 25 hours?

Comment: Yes, show the 23 and 25 hour days some love too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might get you started:

```
0.upto((60 * 24) - 1).each { |m| puts "%02d:%02d:00" % [m / 60, m % 60] }
```

Comment: If you're in a Rails app/have ActiveSupport available you might prefer: `(1.day/60).times { |m| ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can step anyway:

```
require 'date'
today = Date.today.to_datetime
tomorrow = today+1
min = 1.0/(24*60)
today.step(tomorrow, min){|d| p d.strftime("%H:%M:%S")}
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems that `Date#step` changed in 1.9.3 to expecting the step parameter to be in days, where it used to expect seconds.

Also, if you give it a step param wrapped by `ActiveSupport::Duration` (`Date.today.step(Date.tomorrow, 30.minutes.seconds`), it will explode with an "expected numeric" `TypeError`. Fun times debugging a 1.9.3 upgrade here boss.